# apache2 mod_rewrite rule error (although i think i did everything correctly, and have exhausted google's searchresults)

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

this rewrite rule is not hitting it's mark :(

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET)$
    RewriteRule ^/wiki-search/(.+)$ NicerAppWebOS/index.php?app-wikipedia.org-search=$1 [L,END,PT,DPI]
```

apache log (with rewrite:trace6 set in apache sites-enabled config) :

```
[Tue Aug 29 06:30:46.281647 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760088] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 192.168.178.29:45136] 192.168.178.29 - - [192.168.178.29/sid#7ff3a4331d20][rid#7ff3a438f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/192.168.178.29/] add path info postfix: /var/www/192.168.178.29/wiki-search -> /var/www/192.168.178.29/wiki-search/john
[Tue Aug 29 06:30:46.281648 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760088] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 192.168.178.29:45136] 192.168.178.29 - - [192.168.178.29/sid#7ff3a4331d20][rid#7ff3a438f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/192.168.178.29/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/192.168.178.29/wiki-search/john -> wiki-search/john
[Tue Aug 29 06:30:46.281650 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760088] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 192.168.178.29:45136] 192.168.178.29 - - [192.168.178.29/sid#7ff3a4331d20][rid#7ff3a438f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/192.168.178.29/] applying pattern '^/wiki-search/(.+)$' to uri 'wiki-search/john'
[Tue Aug 29 06:30:46.281651 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760088] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 192.168.178.29:45136] 192.168.178.29 - - [192.168.178.29/sid#7ff3a4331d20][rid#7ff3a438f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/192.168.178.29/] add path info postfix: /var/www/192.168.178.29/wiki-search -> /var/www/192.168.178.29/wiki-search/john
[Tue Aug 29 06:30:46.281652 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760088] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 192.168.178.29:45136] 192.168.178.29 - - [192.168.178.29/sid#7ff3a4331d20][rid#7ff3a438f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/192.168.178.29/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/192.168.178.29/wiki-search/john -> wiki-search/john
[Tue Aug 29 06:30:46.281654 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760088] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 192.168.178.29:45136] 192.168.178.29 - - [192.168.178.29/sid#7ff3a4331d20][rid#7ff3a438f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/192.168.178.29/] applying pattern '^/wiki-search/(.+)$' to uri 'wiki-search/john'
[Tue Aug 29 06:30:46.281655 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760088] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 192.168.178.29:45136] 192.168.178.29 - - [192.168.178.29/sid#7ff3a4331d20][rid#7ff3a438f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/192.168.178.29/] add path info postfix: /var/www/192.168.178.29/wiki-search -> /var/www/192.168.178.29/wiki-search/john
[Tue Aug 29 06:30:46.281656 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760088] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 192.168.178.29:45136] 192.168.178.29 - - [192.168.178.29/sid#7ff3a4331d20][rid#7ff3a438f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/192.168.178.29/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/192.168.178.29/wiki-search/john -> wiki-search/john
```

i'm running on Ubuntu 22.04, with the latest apache2 :

```
root@parakeet:/var/www/192.168.178.29/NicerAppWebOS/scripts.maintenance# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2023-05-03T20:02:51
```

and i could really use some mod-rewrite expert help here..

for a demo of the app, see https://nicer.app/wiki/en.wikipedia.org - the search bar doesn't work yet... :(

Comment: RewriteRule ^/wiki-search/(.+)$
should be
 RewriteRule ^wiki-search/(.+)$
instead.

but now i've got a different problem with mod_rewrite - it won't pass the GET HTTP parameters to my PHP script.. any ideas to solve this will be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

ah! some google-ing (and following my own comment in my OP) helped :D

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET)$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} XMLHttpRequest
    RewriteRule ^wiki-search/(.*)$ NicerAppWebOS/logic.AJAX/ajax_get_content.php?app-wikipedia.org-search=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET)$
    RewriteRule ^wiki-search/(.*)$ NicerAppWebOS/index.php?app-wikipedia.org-search=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```